# Google Sheets multiple IF(COUNTIF()) possible in same formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have been googling multiple hours now and still cannot find a solution for a Google Sheets problem.

I have two images, the first image is in the cell A1 and the cellname is called "Image1". The second image is in B1 and the cellname is called "Image2". I have two columns of set names, all names in column1 are related to Image1, all names in column2 are related to Image2.

Column1: K1:K4

Column2: L1:L4

I want the name-related images to be displayed next to the names I write down in another column according to if its a name from column1 (Image1 should be displayed next to it) or a name from column2 (Image2 should be displayed next to it).

D4 = First cell where I start writing down names from column1

G4 = First cell where I start writing down names from coulmn2

If I only write down names from column1 I have no problem to display Image1 next to it. Same with names from column2.

I am using those formulas:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($K$1:$K$4,D4),Image1,"")

=IF(COUNTIF($L$1:$L$4,G4),Image2,"")
```

The images are displayed correctly to the related names.

Now, if I write and mix down names from both columns I don't know how to automatically display the correct image related to the name in the cell.

Is it possible to combine =IF(COUNTIF)) multiple times?

[GoogleSheetsSample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p1dTZKcPOZCWddfAa0y5CWFANnn4FavW4RIGH_Xb_S8/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use them together like this in cell `J12` on your test sheet:

`=IF(COUNTIF($K$1:$K$4,I12),Image1,IF(COUNTIF($L$1:$L$4,I12),Image2,""))`

An `arrayformula` will save you the trouble of dragging down the formula. Add this to cell `J12` and delete all content in `J13:J1000`:

`=arrayformula(IF(COUNTIF(K:K,I12:I),Image1,IF(COUNTIF(L:L,I12:I),Image2,"")))`

[image]

For the `arrayformula` to work, the criterion for each `countif` needs to be from the cell where the formula is located (eg, `J12` in this example), to wherever you want the criterion to keep working to. I've deliberately left it to `:J` so it works to the bottom of the sheet.

The `countif` ranges don't need to be fixed and they can be the entire columns if you wish `K:K` and `L:L`. Or you could set a range if you don't want the `countif` to go past a certain row (eg. `K1:K9` and `L1:L9`).

Comment: Thank you so much, what a relief. I've been trying so many combined formulas over multiple hours. Thanks alot!

Comment: Happy to help :-)

Comment: Thanks, yea I tried to upvote already your answer but I cannot cause I am fresh on the site and need 15 reputation.